# How to add price per kilo (kg)

Tags: magento-1.8, product, price, product-attribute

What's the best way to display the price of the product & display a price per kilo.

We have added in all the weight in grams so I suppose we could do the following

Price Per Kilo = (product price / weight in grams) * 1000

However wanted to see if there was a native way of doing this or a ready built extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ended up doing the maths in the html

```
<div class="price-per-kilo">
    <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency(number_format(((Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice())) / $_product->getWeight()) * 1000,2),true,true); ?>
    <?php echo $this->__("per kilo")?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Germany we have a law for this base price. So there is a module which implements this:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/baseprice-modul-basic-grundpreis-modul-pangv.html

Maybe a newer version is on http://de.nr-apps.com/ but the website is not loading in the moment, so only this link.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything native for this. My recommendation is to develop an extension that either computes it at product load (i.e. product page) or an observer that listens to a product-before-save event and updates it as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the price per KG of your products you could add a new attribute to your products.

If you want to calculate this in your code then you can do it easily.
In your `view.phtml` you could do something like this:

```
<script>
    var price = <?php echo ($_product->getPrice()) ?>;
    var weight = <?php echo ($_product->getWeight()) ?>;
    document.write(price/weight);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this doesn't work for every case, here is the simplest way of making it work.

Create a product called 1Kg - Bananas (just an example) this way to add another Kilo all the customer needs to do is add qty.

Would this work for your case